# Saving a 40000x50000 image works but saving a 45000x50000 does not

Tags: python, image, opencv

I have a uint8 png image that I am trying to save in python using opencv:
`cv2.imwrite('test45.png', im_final_copy[0:45000,0:50000])`

It seems that when I try this, the image saves but when I view it, it's all black, the image size ends up being 2.5 mb. However, when I try to save a `40000x50000` image, the image is not all black and the size of it is 17.5 mb. Does anyone know what the issue is here?

Is there a limitation to `cv2.imwrite`? If so, what could I do to save such a large image? The values of this image are either `0` or `255`. Maybe I need to save it as a binary?

Comment: is `imshow` working fine on both?

Comment: There seems to be something wrong, I tried to create the two variants of images as got `40000x50000 = 2.0MB` and `45000x50000 = 2.3MB`

Comment: @hashcode55 I cannot seem to imshow them due to a lack of memory on my computer

Comment: @ZoomBee Hmm, not sure, but can you try compressing and then writing the image? `params = list();
    params.append(cv.CV_IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION);
    params.append(8)`. Pass `params` as the third parameter to `imwrite`.

Comment: @hashcode55 Still a black image when writing large images. I also tried different image formats (`tiff`, `jpg`) and had the same issue.

Comment: @ZoomBee This is probably a memory related issue. I tried recreating the same thing on my laptop (8 gig) and exceeded my memory limit. BUT when I was doing the same thing with half the dimensions, the image was black until 5-6 seconds.

Comment: How much memory do you have?

Comment: @hashcode55 Been running on my laptop with 16gb of RAM. I tried running on servers with 64gb and 128gb of RAM and it outputs the same black image.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136776/discussion-between-hashcode55-and-zoom-bee).